# Fullcalender eventRecieve Function Not Firing Ajax under Firefox

Tags: ajax, firefox, fullcalendar

We have the following script that works fine on all browsers.

However when the same script is placed inside the Fullcalender eventRecieve function (external events drag, drop and re render) the script does not post data to insert_events.php - but this only happens in Firefox- it does post data as expected in both Chrome and Edge.   So in summary we have a situation as follows:

- Edge, Chrome, FF - script is standalone --> posts data as expected
- Edge and Chrome - script is inside eventRecieve --> posts data as
  expected
- FF script is inside eventRecieve -->fails to post data as expected

Code:

```
var title = "Job Request";
var description = "nothing";
var start = "2017-08-28";
var url = "google.com";
var propertyid = "WR388GG-8621";

$.post("insert_events.php?propertyid=" + propertyid, {
    title: title,
    description: description,
    start: start,
    url: url
  },
  function(data, status) {
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  }
);
```

We originally thought this issue was down to the Ajax code with FF and 
searched high and low for some ideas and spent a day trying to work out what was going on. But actually the problem is only showing up in Firefox and only when  the script is triggered by Fullcalendar's eventRecieve function as below.

Code:

```
eventReceive: function(event) {
  var title = "Job Request";
  var description = "nothing";
  var start = "2017-08-28";
  var url = "google.com";

  $.post("insert_events.php?propertyid=" + id, {
      title: title,
      description: description,
      start: start,
      url: url
    },
    function(data, status) {
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
  window.location = 'new place to go';
},
```

Any ideas?

Comment: any console errors in FF when this happens? Or unusual behaviour in the ajax request (have a look at it in the network tab of your dev tools)

Comment: Also, more obviously: That `window.location` command is almost certainly going to run before your $.post request completes, in any browser, thus cutting off the ajax call. Why are you going to a new page at that point?

Comment: @ ADyson Thanks. In the testing I removed the windows.location redirect. And bear in mind all is working on Chrome and Edge - which couldnt be the case if windows.location was cutting the ajax call off.

Comment: @ ADyson. I suspect the issue is resolving to be with the way the parent function event.Receive is handling the ajax call under FF. I have tested everyway possible in Network, Console and Debugger to find a clue. And absolutely nothing I'm afraid, By all means suggest a test and I will try it - but I suspect the test has already been tried - hence this cry for help with Fullcalender in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Credit goes to A Dyson on this one. It would seem that Firefox alone will trigger the redirect (window.location = 'new place to go';) before the Ajax call is made. The same is not true of Chrome or Edge - which handle the Ajax call first. Please upvote A Dyson's comment which should be the accepted answer. Apologies for dismissing A Dysons correct comment to soon.